# Xcode 11.2 and Simulator extremely slow

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

Yesterday i update my `Xcode 11.1` to `11.2` After update the `Xcode 11.2` and simulators extremely slow. Sometime simulator stuck on application Splash screen. Can anyone now what problem with new `Xcode 11.2` and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this online. Are you using an application like BetterTouchTool? This seems to be a common problem.

> I have found a solution for me. I am using BetterTouchTool and it was the one that was freezing the iOS simulator. So I disabled BetterTouchTool just for the simulator and now it is working normally.

[Link To Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3xg9za/does_anyone_also_have_a_problem_with_freezing_ios/)